# Problem removing iFrame space

Tags: html, css, facebook, iframe

I have a Facebook iFrame button and a Twitter one.
There is space that automatically comes, I have no idea why, and I can't remove it.
There is an image of it-

[image: iFrame issue]

There is no `<br />` or anything that I know that can cause the space.
Thanks in charge.

Comment: Thanks for the English correction Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some sample of your HTML output would be helpful, but you could try adding a css rule:

```
iframe {
 display: inline-block;
}
```

**EDIT**

Looking at your HTML source, I see you have a width specified on the iFrame elements for the twitter and facebook feeds.

```
<iframe allowTransparency='true' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' src='[LONG URL REMOVED]' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:20px'></iframe>
```

If you simply remove the static width from this element, the two frames will sit next to each other. The issue is that the container only has a set amount of width. If you have 500px total and the twitter iFrame is using 110 of that, the other iFrame wants 450... 450 + 110 = 560, more width than you have available. This forces the Facebook iFrame to wrap to the next line.

So again, just take the static width off the Facebook iFrame. As people click "Like", their profile pictures will be added next to the button. Since you won't have a static width specified, the container is free to grow as wide as it needs to.

I would also set `width:100%;` on the container div.

Comment: Thanks Chris, it done the trick. I removed the previous comment because I don't want my site to be published like I said. Thank you